# How might I grant access to everyone's calendar in Exchange 2007?

Tags: permissions, exchange, outlook, powershell, calendar

We're considering changing our users' Outlook calendar permissions for all users so that everyone has "Reviewer" access by default. Since our users primarily use their calendars for business (and can mark personal appointments as private) it makes sense for us to be able to see the details of what each other is up to.

What are some ways that we might be able to push these new positions out to existing calendars? It must be possible with a single PowerShell command, right? Or is there a way to do it from a Group Policy?

Comment: Is it Exchange 2003 or 2007?

Comment: Oh! 2007 - sorry. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with Powershell but it only effects current mailboxes. Future mailboxes won't have that access. What you could do is just do a windows schedule and run the powershell command for it.

Another option is to use the [SetPerm](http://www.amset.info/downloads/Setperm.zip) tool which edited the permissions on the default mailbox. This has the advance of being for all future mailboxes.

Comment: So a combination of the two sounds like it'd work. PowerShell to affect existing mailboxes, SetPerm to change the defaults for future ones? +1 - thanks. (Not accepting any answers just yet - will wait for a bit.)

Comment: So what IS the Powershell command?

Answer (score 3):

There unfortuantley is not an easy PowerShell command to do this, however using [PFDavAdmin](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=635BE792-D8AD-49E3-ADA4-E2422C0AB424&displaylang=en) - the Public Folder DAV admin tool from MS,  you can do so. [This](http://exchangeshare.wordpress.com/2008/05/27/faq-give-calendar-read-permission-on-all-mailboxes-pfdavadmin/) article explains the process in doing so.

Comment: -1 for incorrectly stating it's not possible with powershell
+1 for stating PFDavAdmin

Comment: I don't think he *did* state it wasn't possible.

Answer (score 3):

This can easily done with the [setperm](http://www.amset.info/exchange/folderpermissions.asp) utility.  I've honestly never used it for Exchange 2007 only on Exchange 2003, but it shows as supporting it.  There is also some great screenshots and info here: http://telnetport25.wordpress.com/2007/07/25/exchange-2003-change-mailbox-folders-permissions-in-bulk/

Answer (score 0):

Glen Scales, Exchange MVP and all-around smart guy, has a nifty PowerShell script that gives you a GUI to set calendar permissions (see gsexdev.blogspot.com/2008/03/default-calendar-permission-powershell.html). He also has a script usable with earlier versions of Exchange (see gsexdev.blogspot.com/2005/05/changing-default-permissions-on.html). However, setperm will probably be easier to use than either of these :)